# Getting 404 on Nginx configuration for SSL on subfolder only

Tags: nginx

I need to keep the root of a domain strictly running non SSL but allow a subfolder to use SSL.  The current configuration I took from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398514/nginx-https-when-only-matching-admin-subfolder

When I implement this, I get 404's for both the root of the domain and the subfolder that requires SSL:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name DOMAIN.com www.DOMAIN.com;

    access_log /home/nginx/domains/DOMAIN.com/log/access.log combined;
    error_log /home/nginx/domains/DOMAIN.com/log/error.log;

    location /members {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

    location / {

        root /home/nginx/domains/DOMAIN.com/public;

    #   block common exploits, sql injections etc
    #   include /usr/local/nginx/conf/block.conf;

    #   Enables directory listings when index file not found
        autoindex on;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

    location ~* /(wp-login\.php) {
        limit_req zone=xwplogin burst=1 nodelay;
    #   limit_conn xwpconlimit 30;
    #   auth_basic "Private";
    #   auth_basic_user_file /home/nginx/domains/DOMAIN.com/htpasswd_wplogin;
        include /usr/local/nginx/conf/php-wpsc.conf;
}

    location ~* /(xmlrpc\.php) {
        limit_req zone=xwplogin burst=2 nodelay;
        #limit_conn xwpconlimit 30;
        include /usr/local/nginx/conf/php-wpsc.conf;
}
    location /nginx_status {
        stub_status on;
        access_log   off;
        allow 108.24.115.207;
        deny all;
}

        #include /usr/local/nginx/conf/wpsecure_DOMAIN.com.conf;
        include /usr/local/nginx/conf/staticfiles.conf;
        #include /usr/local/nginx/conf/drop.conf;
        include /usr/local/nginx/conf/php.conf;
        #include /usr/local/nginx/conf/phpstatus.conf;
        #include /usr/local/nginx/conf/errorpage.conf;

}

    server {

    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    server_name DOMAIN.com www.DOMAIN.com;

    ssl_certificate      /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/DOMAINcom/ssl-unified.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/DOMAINcom/ssl.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_session_cache      shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!CAMELLIA;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    add_header Alternate-Protocol  443:npn-spdy/3;
    #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
    add_header  X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    # nginx 1.5.9+ or higher
    # http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_spdy_module.html#spdy_headers_comp
    # http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_buffer_size
    # spdy_headers_comp 0;
    ssl_buffer_size 4k;

    # enable ocsp stapling
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    # ssl_trusted_certificate /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/DOMAINcom/ssl-trusted.crt;

    # ngx_pagespeed &amp; ngx_pagespeed handler
    #include /usr/local/nginx/conf/pagespeed.conf;
    #include /usr/local/nginx/conf/pagespeedhandler.conf;
    #include /usr/local/nginx/conf/pagespeedstatslog.conf;

    # limit_conn limit_per_ip 16;
    # ssi on;

    access_log /home/nginx/domains/DOMAIN.com/log/access.log combined;
    error_log /home/nginx/domains/DOMAIN.com/log/error.log;

    location /members {
        root /home/nginx/domains/DOMAIN.com/public;


}

    location / {
        return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
}

    #include /usr/local/nginx/conf/wpsecure_DOMAIN.com.conf;
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/staticfiles.conf;
    #include /usr/local/nginx/conf/drop.conf;
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/php.conf;
    #include /usr/local/nginx/conf/phpstatus.conf;
    #include /usr/local/nginx/conf/errorpage.conf;
}
```

Comment: What does your nginx error.log say?

Comment: Its trying to use the default vhost path of nginx: 2015/08/07 18:49:47 [error] 28651#28651: *112 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/wp-content/plugins/special-recent-posts-pro/cache/srpthumb-p43776-100x100-no.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: x.x.x.x, server: domain.com, request: "GET /wp-content/plugins/special-recent-posts-pro/cache/srpthumb-p43776-100x100-no.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "www.domain.com", referrer: "http://www.domain.com/2015/08/something/"

Comment: root /home/nginx/domains/DOMAIN.com/public; 

The location is set.